# Save an image Resized with PHP

Tags: php, image, resize, save, editing

I am working on improving my Facebook app. I need to be able to resize an image, then save it to a directory on the server. This is the code I have to resize:

```
<?php
// The file
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$percent = 0.5;

// Content type
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// Get new dimensions
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$new_width = $width * $percent;
$new_height = $height * $percent;

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
?>
```

My question is, how would I save this resized image? Would I need to? Is there a way to **manipulate the resized image without saving it**?

Comment: I don't get that last sentence?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [manual on imagejpeg()](http://www.php.net/imagejpeg), the optional second parameter can specify a file name, which it will be written into.

> **Filename**
>
> The path to save the file to. If not set or NULL, the raw image stream will be outputted directly.
>
> To skip this argument in order to provide the quality parameter, use NULL.

It's usually a good idea to write the results to disk for some basic caching, so that not every incoming request leads to a (resource intensive) GD call.

Comment: Ok, perfect. Only thing I am not liking is that it does display. I decided that it would be better if the image was resized in the background. Is there a way I can force it to just save the resized image, instead of displaying the output?

Comment: @Zachary I don't follow. `$image_p` is already the resized image, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want the resized image to be displayed, just saved. Is this possible?

Comment: @Zachary yes, by specifying the file name as said above. What is missing from that?

Answer (score 3):

```
function resize($img){
/*
only if you script on another folder get the file name
$r =explode("/",$img);
$name=end($r);
*/
//new folder
$vdir_upload = "where u want to move";
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($img);
//ne size
$dst_width = 110;
$dst_height = ($dst_width/$width_orig)*$height_orig;
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($dst_width,$dst_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
imagecopyresampled($im, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $dst_width, $dst_height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
//modive the name as u need
imagejpeg($im,$vdir_upload . "small_" . $name);
//save memory
imagedestroy($im);
}
```

it should be work

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php#90038